# Webkit Browser Development on Windows VS2010

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webkit

I want to build a WebKit Browser on Windows using VS 2010 (preferred but not restricted). I wanted a .net wrapper for the same, I found [Webkit.Net](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) and it worked but seamed so old, then I tried updating WebKit engine in WebKit.Net as shown [here](http://peterdn.com/post/%28First!%29-Using-WebKit-nightly-builds-with-WebKit-NET.aspx) but it didn't work.

I would like to use VB but C# can also be used (but I still prefer VB).

- How do I develop a WebKit Based Browser using VS 2010 (preferred) ?
- Which is the best (and simplest) WebKit .net wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

- [The Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) (Same one used in Github for Windows. can be used with any .Net language)
- [Awesomium](https://awesomium.com/) (free for non commercial apps and Indie devs (making less than $100k/year))